# Receive and send sip in two applications at the same time

Tags: udp, port, sip, voip, sdp

I have a softphone X-lite installed on my computer. i wanted to develop a program in C # to see the sip messages it receives and sends. already built a softphone that does this. but I want it in a standalone application. I'm in trouble because I can not use the same port for two aplications ... someone can help me?

Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Unless you are only using the loopback interface, Wireshark would be a good way to get the SIP flow. It even has a dissector to filter for the SIP protocol.

Comment: You don't have to use the same port for both softphones. UDP 5060 is the default SIP Port but you can use whichever port you want. X-lite lets you specify the local port in its configuration settings so you can easily move it to a different port.

Comment: Thanks for the answers :)

I can not use wireshark because I want to save the SIP messages in a variable for later use in another application.

yes I use two ports, but I want to receive the data coming to my softphone ... just have to use the softphone port 5060 and my application can read messages from the same port... this case also the 5060 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/.)

it is open source tool. Try and run the *pjsua* application. It will let you make/receive calls from any port of you choice. It will act as a UAS/UAC. You can also register your X-lite client at this port.

E.g. pjsua --local-port=5090

Detailed usage of [pjsua](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm)